# Using vim to force write a file that has been modified on the file system

Tags: vim

After interactively rebasing with git, I frequently find that a file I have open in vim has been modified on the file system. When I go to write the file with `:w` or `:w!`, I get the prompt `WARNING: The file has been changed since reading it!!!`/`Do you really want to write to it (y/n)?`.

I consider this warning reasonable enough; it would be questionable behavior to silently overwrite a file on the file system that has changed for an arbitrary reason. However, in cases like this where I know why the file has been touched, I often find that I want to force write it instead of having to check whether there's a prompt or not. I've had situations where I haven't noticed the prompt and have immediately tabbed away resulting in inconsistent builds and, occasionally, loss of data.

How do I get rid of the confirmation prompt, either permanently or (preferably) with an expanded command analogous to `w!`?

When I Google this, I get a bunch of hits for force writing a read-only file with `w!`, but I can't seem to find anything dealing with force writing a modified file.

Comment: Try this command: `:w !sudo tee %`.

Comment: This is pretty close to an answer. However, if I have unsaved files (or files that were saved at a different point in history) in other viewports of a split screen, I get a W11 or W12 warning. E.g., when trying to save `foo.c` using the method you mentioned, I'm seeing `Warning: File "path/to/bar" has changed and the buffer was changed in Vim as well`/`See ":help W12" for more info"`. The help for W11 suggests setting `autoread` which isn't what I want.

Answer (score 0):

The following command works for the current buffer
(I don't know of a solution for multiple buffers):

```
:w !sudo tee %
```

The character `%` stands for the current file name.
The `sudo` command allows the overwriting of files opened as
read-only.

To define `:w!!` as command that does the above, add this to `.vimrc`:

```
cmap w!! w !sudo tee > /dev/null %
```

The `> /dev/null` part eliminates the standard output of `tee` which
is not used here.

For more information see the post
[How does the vim "write with sudo" trick work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2600783/how-does-the-vim-write-with-sudo-trick-work)

Comment: This is almost a full solution, but triggers additional (and fairly annoying) warnings if other buffers are modified in vim. However, I learned about `cmap` today; thank you.